# How does a given JSP know the request and response from the servlet where it was redirected from?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I don't have a problem, I got curious about it.

**This is the code in my JSP**

```
<%
    String email =  "User doesn't Exist"; 
    HttpSession mySession = request.getSession();
    if (mySession != null){
        email = (String) request.getAttribute("email");
    }else {
        // This request and response were defined in the servlet 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
%>
```

So the question as I wrote in the title, how does the JSP know them.
If there are any further need of clarification just ask.

Answer (score -1):

They are JSP *implicit objects*.

[What is meant by JSP implicit objects and what are they?](https://medium.com/interviewhackingninja/20-java-interview-questions-4-a3c98cae1999)

> These objects are created by the JSP engine during the translation phase (when a JSP is translated into a servlet). Implicit objects are a set of Java objects that the JSP specification provides for developers to access and manipulate the data associated with a particular `request`, `response`, `session`, etc.

You can read about implicit objects in JSP in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html).

> The servlet container creates an [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [`HttpServletResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) objects and passes them as arguments to the servlet's service methods (`doGet`, `doPost`, etc).

See [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class documentation for more details.

Comment: You forgot to add the link to the source where you copypasted the first blockquote from: https://medium.com/interviewhackingninja/20-java-interview-questions-4-a3c98cae1999 The first sentence of the last paragraph should also be in a blockquote because it's copypasted from the javadocs of HttpServletRequest/Response.