# Servlet URL mapping and filter mapping -- can't get both to work together

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-mapping

In my web.xml I have a servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dir/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and I also have a filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>filters.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.data</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If I access `/dir` or `/dir/foo`, the servlet responds. If I access `/somewhere/file.data`, the filter filters the response. If I access `/dir/foo.data`, I just get a 404 error.

I have tried reversing the order of the servlet and the filter in my web.xml file, but it makes no difference. It seems that I can either get the servlet to respond, or the filter to filter the response, but not both.

Can anyone tell me what to do to get the servlet to respond and also have the filter process the servlet response?

Comment: What do you mean "the filter process the servlet response"? The response object is sent to the filter as a method parameter. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77665795/573032).

Comment: The servlet returns copies of "files" which actually come from a database. The filter replaces marked strings in certain files with i18n translations. What I'm trying to do is get a "file" from the DB (the "pathname" of which is given as the wildcard after "/dir/") and have the marked strings that it contains translated if the extension matches the filter mapping, just like real files of the same type. The problem is that the servlet will only serve up a file from the DB if the file extension is not ".data". Real files with this extension are translated as expected.

Comment: In other words, the filter processes "/dir/foo.data" (which doesn't actually exists, it's supposed to be an artefact created from what's in the DB) and since it doesn't exist I get a 404. The servlet never gets called to process the request and generate the artefact. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: What will be if you add extention mapping to the servlet?

Comment: How do you mean? I can't do "/dir/*.data" as that isn't legal according to the servlet spec -- but is that what you meant?

Comment: The servlet can map both mappings, either delimited in the same string or used in another tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256299/discussion-between-user1636349-and-roman-c).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no easy way to solve this, since filter mappings always seem to take precedence over servlet mappings. (I can't see anything in the servlet spec which mandates this, but this is how it appears to work.) The only solution I've found is to get rid of the filter altogether and merge its functionality into the servlet.

I now have a servlet which responds to `/dir/*` and also to `*.data`. It inspects the request URI, and if it starts with `/dir/` it generates the response dynamically, otherwise it just processes the corresponding file. Then, if the URI ends with `.data`, it preprocesses the response in the same way as the filter used to do.

The disadvantage is that this causes a maintenance problem, as the servlet needs to know which patterns it is configured to respond to in the `web.xml` file. To minimise the problem, the servlet mapping now looks like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
<!--
  If the patterns below are changed, the "prefixes" and
  "suffixes" list in the servlet source code need to be
  updated to match, and the servlet needs to be recompiled.
-->
  <url-pattern>/dir/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.data</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the servlet I have this:

```
public static final String[] prefixes = new String[] {
  "/dir/"
};
public static final String[] suffixes = new String[] {
  ".data"
};
```

so the servlet can match the URI against the contents of each array. It's a bit messy, but it's the best I can do.